# Type defenition don't work in@ManyToOne association whith entity which have composite embedded primary key JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, primary-key, many-to-one

I use JPA interface, provider - Hibernate. One entity have embedded primary key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CD_CONTROL")
public class CdControl extends BaseDAO<CdControl> {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CdControlPk id;

    @Column(name = "CD_CONTROL_NAME")
    private String cdControlName;

    //   ...

    public CdControlPk getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(CdControlPk id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //   ...

}
```

In embedded primary key I defined database type of columns type of properties in 
**columnDefinition** attribute of **@Coloumn** annotation:

```
@Embeddable
public class CdControlPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="CONTROL_KEY", columnDefinition = "RAW")
    private String controlKey;

    @Column(name="CONTROL_OWNER_KEY", columnDefinition = "RAW")
    private String controlOwnerKey;

    //  ...
}
```

In database associate coloumn have type **RAW**. It id used database **Oracle 10g**. I have entity which have **ManyToOne** assosiation with **CdControl**:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="CD_PROPERTY_VALUE")
    public class CdPropertyValue extends BaseDAO<CdPropertyValue> implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        private CdPropertyValuePK id;

        @Column(name="VALUE")
        private String value;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to CdControl
        @ManyToOne 
        @MapsId("id")   
        @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_OWNER_KEY", referencedColumnName ="CONTROL_OWNER_KEY", 
            columnDefinition="RAW", insertable=false,updatable=false),
          @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_KEY", referencedColumnName = "CONTROL_KEY", 
            columnDefinition="RAW", insertable=false,updatable=false )
                })
        private CdControl cdControl;

        //   ...
    }
```

Here I also explicitly pointed **RAW** type in **@JoinColoumn**. In **EntityManagerProperties**  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`. Hibernate version - 5.1.1 FINAL. But application fails on start on the database validation stage. In stacktrace I see next exception:

*Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [CONTROL_KEY] in table [CD_PROPERTY_VALUE]; **found [raw (Types#VARBINARY)], but expecting [varchar2(255 char) (Types#VARCHAR)]***

In connection with mentioned I have a question: where else I have specify Type to Hibernate pick it up? Or may be I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It began to work when type in all associations with **CdControl** was pointed to **RAW** , not only **CdPropertyValue**. Shema-validator error message in this situation is confused.